# Find value for a key from a dynamic json using java

Tags: java, json, search

I need to get the value of the key from a dynamic json.
Input-> json Object, String key
Output-> json element(corresponds to the value of the key)
Example

JsonObject Jmsg =

```
{
  "id": "1753_CORE1",
  "name": "Gtx cuda Service:1753",
  "shortName": "gt-service-1753",
  "createdDate": "Mar 31, 2015 4:47:10 PM",
  "config": {
    "oauthSecret": [
      {
        "id": 45,
        "config123": {
          "oauthSecret": "P8n2x5Hsst0nFRRB0A",
          "status": "CREATED"
        },
        "SERVER132": "1000"
      },
      {
        "id": 46,
        "config123": {
          "oauthSecret": "P8n2x5Htss0nFRRB0A"
        },
        "SERVER132": "1000"
      }
    ],
    "oauthKey": "154284-service-1753",
    "SERVER": "1000"
  },
  "features": [
    9004,
    9005
  ]
}
```

and String key = "status";
then
JsonElement Jvalue = jsonGetValueformKey(Jmsg,key);
should return 'CREATED' in JsonElement or string type.

if String key = "features";
then
JsonElement Jvalue = jsonGetValueformKey(Jmsg,key);
should return [9004,9005] in JsonElement or jsonArray type.

if key not found then return null
JsonObject Jmsg can be anything

Comment: I assume you currently use `Gson`, so i recommend to take a look on the `entrySet()` method, which returns all members of your Element. From there you can work with loops or recursive through all fields. But be careful with e.g. `String key = "id"`

Comment: Yes .. I am using `Gson` 
implementation using Gson will be helpful

Comment: And how do you plan to work with keys inside a `JsonArray` like `"config123"` or with keys like `"id"` that even appear on different layers?

Comment: yes.. json can be anything. ... it might even not have that key which we are searching

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. please provide an expected output of your sample when you search the key `"config123"` or `"oauthSecret"` or `"id"`

Comment: ohh ok .. i got what you are trying to say..
in a case of multiple occurnce of the key .. it should return array of values ..
like for `"config123"` it should return [{
          "oauthSecret": "P8n2x5Hsst0nFRRB0A",
          "status": "CREATED"
        },{
          "oauthSecret": "P8n2x5Htss0nFRRB0A"
        }]
and for `"id"` it should return [1753_CORE1,45,46]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please try this

```
package json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class MyApp {
    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String key = "oauthSecret";

        String json2 = "{\"config\": {\"oauthSecret\": [{\"id\": 45,\"config123\": {\"oauthSecret\": \"P8n2x5Ht0nFRRB0A\",\"status\": \"CREATED\"},\"SERVER132\": \"1000\"},{\"id\": 46,\"config123\": {\"oauthSecret\": \"wP8n2x5Ht0nFRRB0A\",\"status\": \"CREATED\"},\"SERVER132\": \"1000\"}],\"oauthKey\": \"newtest\",\"SERVER\": \"1000\"},\"features\": [ 9004, 9005] ,\"d\":\"dd\"}";

        System.out.println("JSON: " + json2);
        JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
        check(key, p.parse(json2));
        System.out.println("list size: " + list.size());
        System.out.println(list);
    }



    private static void check(String key, JsonElement jsonElement) {

        if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
            for (JsonElement jsonElement1 : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
                check(key, jsonElement1);
            }
        } else {
            if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonElement
                        .getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
                    String key1 = entry.getKey();
                    if (key1.equals(key)) {
                        list.add(entry.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    check(key, entry.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                if (jsonElement.toString().equals(key)) {
                    list.add(jsonElement.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you sure with this code
`check(key,entry.getValue().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));`
it will send `9004,9005` as json

Comment: @ChinmaySamant I think it works now, please check updated code I tested all cases

Comment: You sure This will work in a case of multiple occurnce of the key .. it should return array of values

Comment: i feel insted of `return;` it should add it to a list

Comment: like for "config123" it should return [{ "oauthSecret": "P8n2x5Hsst0nFRRB0A", "status": "CREATED" },{ "oauthSecret": "P8n2x5Htss0nFRRB0A" }] and for "id" it should return [1753_CORE1,45,46]

Comment: in my data sample, oauthSecret has array, the result is [{"id":45,"config123":{"oauthSecret":"P8n2x5Ht0nFRRB0A","status":"CREATED"},"SERVER132":"1000"}]

Answer (score 5):

This is a draft of a recursive approach for that.

```
Object find(JSONObject jObj, String k) throws JSONException {
    Iterator<?> keys = jObj.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        if (key.equals(k)) {
            return jObj.get(key);
        }

        if ( jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
            return find((JSONObject)jObj.get(key), k);
        }

        if ( jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray ) {
            JSONArray jar = (JSONArray)jObj.get(key);
            for (int i = 0; i < jar.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j = jar.getJSONObject(i);
                find(j, k);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :-

```
public Object checkKey(JSONObject object, String searchedKey) {
    boolean exists = object.containsKey(searchedKey);
    Object obj = null;
    if(exists){
        obj = object.get(searchedKey);
    }
    if(!exists) {      
         Set<String> keys = object.keySet();
         for(String key : keys){
             if ( object.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
                 obj = checkKey((JSONObject)object.get(key), searchedKey);
            }
         }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

This will give you the Object type for a key OR null if key does not exists.
You can modify it & caste the return `Object` type to any `JSONObject`, `String` or `JSONArray` depending upon your condition by checking its class using `getClass()`.

Note :- This is just a reference but you can edit it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Object findJsonParam(JSONObject payload, String param) {
    Iterator<?> keys = payload.keys();

    System.out.println("payload  " + payload);

    while (keys.hasNext()) {

        String key = (String) keys.next();
        if (key.equals(param)) {
            return payload.get(key);
        } else if (payload.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {

            Object val = findJsonParam(payload.getJSONObject(key), param);
            if (val != null)
                return val;
        } else if (payload.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jar = payload.getJSONArray(key);
            for (Object jsonObj : jar) {
                Object val = findJsonParam((JSONObject) jsonObj, param);
                if (val != null)
                    return val;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some changes in [DrB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3221017/drb) awnser, it worked for me this way. Because on the first nested json it returned without checking the value, so if the key wasn't in the first one, then it couldn't find it.

```
public Object find(JSONObject jObj, String k) throws JSONException {
    Iterator<?> keys = jObj.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        if (key.equals(k)) {
            return jObj.get(key);
        }

        if (jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            Object probableKeyValue = find((JSONObject) jObj.get(key), k);
            if(probableKeyValue != null){
                return probableKeyValue;
            }
        }

        if (jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jar = (JSONArray) jObj.get(key);
            for (int i = 0; i < jar.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j = jar.getJSONObject(i);
                find(j, k);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```