# Get Particular key and their value

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON Data and I need to find any particular key and their Value if that key is available in that json, I need to find their isActive status.

For example, I need to find the key "featureCD" and their value as "EXLVL" if this key is available, I need to find out the isActive status and their value of that  "EXLVL"

Thanks in advance for helping me out on this.

This is my json data:

```
    [
  {
   "featureCD": "EXLVL",
   "featureName": "Experience Personalization",
   "moduleName": "Builder",
   "isActive": true
 },
 {
   "featureCD": "FCLDR",
   "featureName": "Calendar Date UI Update",
   "moduleName": "Builder",
   "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "FDNID",
   "featureName": "Document Name in Download",
  "moduleName": "Builder",
  "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "FDNST",
  "featureName": "Do Not Show Tips Toggle",
  "moduleName": "Dashboard",
  "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "Feature_201",
  "featureName": "sDneB",
  "moduleName": "Dashboard",
  "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "Feature_410",
  "featureName": "mOnuz",
  "moduleName": "Dashboard",
  "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "Feature_515",
  "featureName": "TestTDhSE",
  "moduleName": "Dashboard",
  "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "FGYRU",
   "featureName": "Graduation Year Update",
  "moduleName": "Builder",
  "isActive": true
},
{
  "featureCD": "FMEDP",
 "featureName": "RWZ Mobile  Email Download Popup",
  "moduleName": "Builder",
  "isActive": true
 },
 {
  "featureCD": "FRMTI",
  "featureName": "RWZ Mobile TTC Interaction",
   "moduleName": "Builder",
  "isActive": true
},
 {
   "featureCD": "HSTAD",
   "featureName": "Hide Street Address",
   "moduleName": "Builder",
   "isActive": true
 },
 {
   "featureCD": "OPNTD",
   "featureName": "Open Template Drawer - EB-9307",
   "moduleName": "Builder",
   "isActive": true
 },
 {
  "featureCD": "SAUTO",
   "featureName": "Smart Autocomplete EB-9682",
   "moduleName": "Builder",
   "isActive": true
 }
]
```

Comment: may be this can also solve your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157781/find-value-for-a-key-from-a-dynamic-json-using-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `optString` which returns the empty string ("") if the key you specify doesn't exist. `getString` on the other hand throws a JSONException if the key does not exist.

Something like,

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
// Logic to Iterate through JSONArray, and get individual JSONObject
if(json.optString("featureCD").equals("EXLVL"){
     boolean isActive = json.getBoolean("isActive");
}
```

Docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Also, this would help https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json

Comment: my json is a jsonArray so, when I would be using JSONObject json = new JSONObject(<YOUR STRING HERE>), this will throw an error and will never go to next step of execution...

Comment: Just replace with `JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);` depending on your requirement. I could only provide a generic idea. Implementation is left to you!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a JSON path implementation such as https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath which can be used to solve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectMapper`.

First create your class

```
public class JsonData
{
    private String featureName;

    private String featureCD;

    private String moduleName;

    private Boolean isActive;

    // getter setter
}
```

Then do

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<JsonData> jsonData= mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<JsonData>>(){});
```

And then voila you can do whatever you want with your list of objects. For instance

```
List<JsonData> ExlvlAndActiveData = jsonData.stream().filter(data->data.getFeatureCd().equals("EXLVL") && data.isActive).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `JsonPath` it's very simple and versitale. Especially if you use POJO.

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Usage:

```
JsonPath path = new JsonPath.from(json); //String or File
```

Your JSON consists of fo Array of Objects.
We need to create an object which corresponds to your JSON Object in java like this:

```
public class FeatureObject { //name irrelevant
    public String featureCD; //this name corresponds the name in JSON
    public String featureName; //it's crucial!
    public String moduleName;
    public Boolean isActive;
}
```

and then we parse JSON into Java Objects like this. Note that we have Array of objects so we parse it to array

```
List<FeatureObject> features = Arrays.asList(path.getObject("$", FeatureObject[].class));
```

Now, all we have to do is get the desired feature from the `List` and check it's active status.

I used Java Stream API but you can use regular `for` loop.

Example:

```
Boolean isFeatureActive = features.stream().filter(x -> x.featureCD.equals("EXLVL")).map(x -> x.isActive).findFirst().get();
System.out.println(isFeatureActive);
```

Hope it helps!